toPandas().to_csv() working in Apache Spark V3.3 but not V3.4
We are using Azure Synapses, there has been a notice from Microsoft to say that v3.3 is being removed in 2025. Getting a head of the game, I created a new Pool using v3.4 and moved over our notebooks.
All worked except the notebooks that are writing single CSV's to Gen2 Data Lake storage using toPandas().to_csv() with authentication error (below). Nothing else has changed, and just moving the notebook back to a v3.3 pool it works.
Does anyone have an idea why it is not working in 3.4?
localPathForFiles = "abfss://[container]@[storageaccount].dfs.core.windows.net/extracts/customer-data/{0}/".format(CustomerName)
Df.toPandas().to_csv(localPathForFiles + TaskTypesFileName, lineterminator="\r\n", index=False, header=True, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
I have made sure that the workspace has Storage Blob Data Contributor.
I have included a link server to the directory in storage within Synapses and then included the storage_options: { linked_server: '[linkedserver]'}
Just recreating a 3.3 pool and repointing the notebook, works. This points (for me) to either a package needs to be updated or a bug of some type. - Hopefully just a package!
Full Error Message
ClientAuthenticationError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adlfs/spec.py:2030, in AzureBlobFile._async_upload_chunk(self, final, **kwargs)
2027 async with self.container_client.get_blob_client(
2028     blob=self.blob
2029 ) as bc:
2030     await bc.stage_block(
2031         block_id=block_id,
2032         data=chunk,
2033         length=len(chunk),
2034     )
2035     self._block_list.append(block_id)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator_async.py:77, in distributed_trace_async.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
76 if span_impl_type is None:
77     return await func(*args, **kwargs)
79 # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/aio/_blob_client_async.py:1644, in BlobClient.stage_block(self, block_id, data, length, **kwargs)
1643 except HttpResponseError as error:
1644     process_storage_error(error)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py:184, in process_storage_error(storage_error)
182 try:
183     # `from None` prevents us from double printing the exception (suppresses generated layer error context)
184     exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec
185 except SyntaxError as exc:

File <string>:1

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/aio/_blob_client_async.py:1642, in BlobClient.stage_block(self, block_id, data, length, **kwargs)
1641 try:
1642     return await self._client.block_blob.stage_block(**options)
1643 except HttpResponseError as error:

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator_async.py:77, in distributed_trace_async.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
76 if span_impl_type is None:
77     return await func(*args, **kwargs)
79 # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/aio/operations/_block_blob_operations.py:645, in BlockBlobOperations.stage_block(self, block_id, content_length, body, transactional_content_md5, transactional_content_crc64, timeout, request_id_parameter, lease_access_conditions, cpk_info, cpk_scope_info, **kwargs)
644 if response.status_code not in [201]:
645     map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
646     error = self._deserialize.failsafe_deserialize(_models.StorageError, pipeline_response)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/exceptions.py:164, in map_error(status_code, response, error_map)
163 error = error_type(response=response)
164 raise error

ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:b7074898-501e-007f-4337-e989a8000000
Time:2024-08-08T02:07:05.0273937Z
ErrorCode:NoAuthenticationInformation
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>NoAuthenticationInformation</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:b7074898-501e-007f-4337-e989a8000000
Time:2024-08-08T02:07:05.0273937Z</Message></Error>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 9
7 typesDf = spark.read.jdbc(url=serverCommsConnectionString, table=typesSql, properties=connectionCommsProperties)
8 #Write to storage
9 typesDf.toPandas().to_csv(localPathForFiles + TaskTypesFileName, lineterminator="\r\n", index=False, header=True, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)        

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
209     else:
210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3720, in NDFrame.to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, lineterminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
3709 df = self if isinstance(self, ABCDataFrame) else self.to_frame()
3711 formatter = DataFrameFormatter(
3712     frame=df,
3713     header=header,
>    (...)
3717     decimal=decimal,
3718 )
3720 return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
3721     path_or_buf,
3722     lineterminator=lineterminator,
3723     sep=sep,
3724     encoding=encoding,
3725     errors=errors,
3726     compression=compression,
3727     quoting=quoting,
3728     columns=columns,
3729     index_label=index_label,
3730     mode=mode,
3731     chunksize=chunksize,
3732     quotechar=quotechar,
3733     date_format=date_format,
3734     doublequote=doublequote,
3735     escapechar=escapechar,
3736     storage_options=storage_options,
3737 )

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
209     else:
210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py:1189, in DataFrameRenderer.to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, lineterminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
1168     created_buffer = False
1170 csv_formatter = CSVFormatter(
1171     path_or_buf=path_or_buf,
1172     lineterminator=lineterminator,
>    (...)
1187     formatter=self.fmt,
1188 )
1189 csv_formatter.save()
1191 if created_buffer:
1192     assert isinstance(path_or_buf, StringIO)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:241, in CSVFormatter.save(self)
237 """
238 Create the writer & save.
239 """
240 # apply compression and byte/text conversion
241 with get_handle(
242     self.filepath_or_buffer,
243     self.mode,
244     encoding=self.encoding,
245     errors=self.errors,
246     compression=self.compression,
247     storage_options=self.storage_options,
248 ) as handles:
249 
250     # Note: self.encoding is irrelevant here
251     self.writer = csvlib.writer(
252         handles.handle,
253         lineterminator=self.lineterminator,
>    (...)
258         quotechar=self.quotechar,
259     )
261     self._save()

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:133, in IOHandles.__exit__(self, *args)
132 def __exit__(self, *args: Any) -> None:
133     self.close()

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:125, in IOHandles.close(self)
123     self.created_handles.remove(self.handle)
124 for handle in self.created_handles:
125     handle.close()
126 self.created_handles = []
127 self.is_wrapped = False

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adlfs/spec.py:1903, in AzureBlobFile.close(self)
1901 """Close file and azure client."""
1902 asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(close_container_client(self), loop=self.loop)
1903 super().close()

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py:1932, in AbstractBufferedFile.close(self)
1930 else:
1931     if not self.forced:
1932         self.flush(force=True)
1934     if self.fs is not None:
1935         self.fs.invalidate_cache(self.path)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py:1803, in AbstractBufferedFile.flush(self, force)
1800         self.closed = True
1801         raise
1803 if self._upload_chunk(final=force) is not False:
1804     self.offset += self.buffer.seek(0, 2)
1805     self.buffer = io.BytesIO()

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py:118, in sync_wrapper.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
115 @functools.wraps(func)
116 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
117     self = obj or args[0]
118     return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py:103, in sync(loop, func, timeout, *args, **kwargs)
101     raise FSTimeoutError from return_result
102 elif isinstance(return_result, BaseException):
103     raise return_result
104 else:
105     return return_result

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py:56, in _runner(event, coro, result, timeout)
54     coro = asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=timeout)
55 try:
56     result[0] = await coro
57 except Exception as ex:
58     result[0] = ex

File ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adlfs/spec.py:2067, in AzureBlobFile._async_upload_chunk(self, final, **kwargs)
2063                 await bc.commit_block_list(
2064                     block_list=block_list, metadata=self.metadata
2065                 )
2066         else:
2067             raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to upload block{e}!") from e
2068 elif self.mode == "ab":
2069     async with self.container_client.get_blob_client(blob=self.blob) as bc:

RuntimeError: Failed to upload blockServer failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:b7074898-501e-007f-4337-e989a8000000
Time:2024-08-08T02:07:05.0273937Z
ErrorCode:NoAuthenticationInformation
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>NoAuthenticationInformation</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:b7074898-501e-007f-4337-e989a8000000
Time:2024-08-08T02:07:05.0273937Z</Message></Error>!



ERROR:

RuntimeError: Failed to upload blockServer failed to authenticate the
request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate
header. RequestId:b7074898-501e-007f-4337-e989a8000000
Time:2024-08-08T02:07:05.0273937Z
ErrorCode:NoAuthenticationInformation

The error is relted to authentication methods and the authentication could vary between SDK versions.
In v3.4, a newer version of the Azure SDK might be in use, which could have different default settings or require additional configurations.
As you mentioned that you are trying the
localPathForFiles = "abfss://[container]@[storageaccount].dfs.core.windows.net/extracts/customer-data/{0}/".format(CustomerName).

In order to avoid the ERROR related to NoAuthenticationInformation. you can use the Shared Access Signature.
The below is the URL:
https://<YOUR STORGE ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTINER NAME>/<FOLDER PATH >?<SAS KEY>

Reference:
Avoiding “AuthorizationFailed” error when hand-crafting Shared Access Signature for Azure Storage
How to fix Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header

Thanks I will try. I was trying to keep with the adfss, as this seems faster than https:// but in this case there is only 1 or 2 writes to the blob storage.
I will update shortly.
